# Materialize SASS - is it necessary to include the entire JS file?

Tags: javascript, html, sass, materialize

I am using the SASS version of the Materialize CSS framework.
I only make use of three javascript components.

For the JS components this currently works:

```
<!-- Scripts-->
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bin/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Components initialized in the file below -->
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

But the SASS version of Materialize has a folder with separate JS files.
I only need **materialbox.js**, **scrollspy.js**, **sidenav.js** for my project.

Is there a way to include only what I need instead of the framework's entire JS file?

Including the chosen small JS files in index.html doesn't work